# PDO PHP dual record insert

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Code below inserts single record twice.

Note:

there is no other code in a script besides what you see below (except for DB_HOST, DB_NAME etc. constants).

code:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''));

$array = array(
    '2' => '13'
);

$sql = "INSERT INTO htdopen.oc_product_option (product_id, option_id, required) 
           VALUES (:product_id, :option_id, '1')";
$stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);

foreach ((array)$array as $key => $val)
{
    $stm->bindParam(':product_id', $key, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stm->bindParam(':option_id', $val, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stm->execute();

}
```

output:  (record entered twice, instead of once)

```
+-------------------+------------+-----------+-------+----------+
| product_option_id | product_id | option_id | value | required |
+-------------------+------------+-----------+-------+----------+
|                 1 |          2 |        13 |       |        1 |
|                 2 |          2 |        13 |       |        1 |
+-------------------+------------+-----------+-------+----------+
```

EDIT:

I changed code to output something on the screen and a counter.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''));

$array = array(
    '2' => '13'
);

$sql = "INSERT INTO htdopen.oc_product_option (product_id, option_id, required) 
           VALUES (:product_id, :option_id, '1')";
$stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$c = 0;
foreach ((array)$array as $key => $val)
{
    $c++;
    echo $c . '. ' . $key .'=>'. $val . '
';

    $stm->bindParam(':product_id', $key, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stm->bindParam(':option_id', $val, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stm->execute();

}
```

.... and this is the output on the screen - single line - yet 2 records added .. again - weird:

[image]

Comment: How are you calling your script? Through ajax or on form submission etc?

Comment: Neither Ajax, nor submit. Just simple on-page-load tester. Simple, single page script with nothing else you just see.

Comment: Strange. Can you verify that the loop only runs once? Try to output something inside.

Comment: There is one way this can happen, and it's when you call the script twice.

Comment: do you have any insert triggers?

Comment: I added some counter to code and on-screen output. There is no other code in play except for what you see above (except for DB_HOST and other constants) ... nothing links to the script, I made sure, I truncated table before every script run .. just weird ... maybe it is time to re-instal my WAMP?

Comment: OK, I just tested that online ... and it works fine ... so it is my localhosted WAMP  ... sorry to bother